# Exact Number of flops for Square and Multiply $A^{k}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was wondering what the total number of flops to compute $A^{k}$ for $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ using the square and multiply approach. It is known that it is $O(2\log_{2}(k)n^{3})$ but I searched for the exact number of flops and couldn't find what the exact number of flop is and how it's derived

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying two square $n\times n$ matrix takes $(2n-1)n^2=2n^3-n^2$ flops, according to this [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2427094/computing-flops-for-matrix-multiplication).

Now we consider how many "big" matrix multiplications are there in $A^k$. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question, but I believe there are many variations of "Square and Multiply", each of which will give different answers. Implementation details such as iterative/recursive and memoization changes the answer as well. I will consider this procedure and two implementations.

$$A^0=I$$
$$A^1=A$$
$$A^{2k}=A^k\times A^k$$
$$A^{2k+1}=A\times A^K\times A^K$$

---

1. If every time $A^k$ is required it's re-calculated (you don't remember previous calculation results), we can write out the number of **matrix multiplication** (again, not FLOPs) results

$$T(0)=T(1)=0$$
$$T(2k)=2T(k)+1$$
$$T(2k+1)=2T(k)+2$$

One can prove that $T(k)=k-1$

2. If previous results of $A^k$ are memoized (i.e. remembered/stored), only one copy of $A^k$ has to be calculated. Therefore,

$$T(0)=T(1)=0$$
$$T(2k)=T(k)+1$$
$$T(2k+1)=T(k)+2$$

In this case, you can derive the explicit formula $T(k)=\lfloor\log_2{k}\rfloor+popcount(k)-1$. Refer to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) for information on popcount.

---

Finally after everything, you know the number of big matrix multiplication. Recalling that each big matrix multiplication takes $2n^3-n^2$ flops, number of flops required for $A^k$ will be $$\fbox{$(\lfloor\log_2{k}\rfloor+popcount(k)-1)(2k^3-k^2)$}$$ (or $(k-1)(2k^3-k^2)$, but that's not what your $O$ suggests.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, indeed the total number of flops doesn't look beautiful

Comment: Is there any estimate for the values of $popcount$ in such case because I have read the wikipedia article and couldn't understand its significance, can $popcount(k)-1$ be relatively negligible?

Comment: @Readmybiopls I should have explained myself cuz the page is pretty bad but i was lazy lol. $popcount$ is essentially the number of set bits in binary of $k$, i.e. if $k=21=0b10101$ then $popcount(k)=3$. As you can see it's bounded above by $\lceil\log_2{k}\rceil$. There isn't much approximation/estimate apart from that the average of popcount between $2^k$ and $2^{k+1}-1$ is $1+\frac{k}{2}$, if that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much once more for your excellent answer